# How do I make an array of linked lists as a variable for my java class?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test {
    private LinkedList<object>[] array = new LinkedList[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++){
        array[i] = new LinkedList<hashNode>();
        }
}
```

This is the code that I have which is far off from right, I know that I need to initialize a new LinkedList for each position in the array but I can't figure out how to do that within the class. I basically want an array of ten linked lists to be the variable of my object and I'm stumped on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in an initializer block:

```
public class Test {
    ...
    private LinkedList<object>[] array = new LinkedList[10];
    ...
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = new LinkedList<hashNode>();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Or in the constructor:

```
public class Test {
    ...
    private LinkedList<object>[] array = new LinkedList[10];
    ...
    public Test () {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = new LinkedList<hashNode>();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Note also that Java is case-sensitive, and unless you've defined something named `object`, you probably meant `Object`, or you can use a wildcard `?`.

By the way, your loop condition was incorrect in your example, you meant `i < array.length`, not `i < 0`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! that makes sense, I was a little unsure how constructors worked. I assumed it was literally just "this.example = variable" to set things and that's it.